# Classic ASP how to upload multiple files html5

Tags: html, file, vbscript, upload, asp-classic

I'm really new to Classic ASP/VBscript. I'm trying to upload multiple files through Ajax. 
The code below works if only one file has selected. 
What I need to know is the way to access to each files if multiple files selected. I've been searching for the answer but no luck so far.

html code

```
<form id="uploadform"> 
<input type="file" name="thefile" id="thefile" multiple>
<input type="button" onclick="uploadfile(this.value)" value="click">
</form>
```

Classic ASP
(This return the filename.)

```
Option Explicit
Dim objUploadd

Set objUpload = Server.CreateObject("ASPUploadComponent.cUpload")

Response.Write (objUpload.Form("thefile").value)
```

Comment: Hi. There are many free online resources for learning classic ASP as a beginner. Please consider doing some more research.

Comment: Don't know if this helps in your specific scenario but there's a very useful multiple file upload script here - http://www.uploadify.quickersite.com/index.html

Comment: Yes would suggest the same Uploadify works really well! http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: Thank you so much guys. I was almost giving this up. I'll try the uploadify. 
@VanquishedWombat  Yes, I will learn it when I have time. I just don't have enough time now.

Comment: How about trying to add multiple inputs to start off with?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a form which submits multiple values of the same form variable you can separate them as follows.

```
For i = 1 to Request.form("myforminput").Count
    If Request.form("myforminput")(i) <> "" then
        Response.write Request.form("myforminput")(i) & "<br />"
    End if
Next
```

It might be worth trying the same approach - ie:

```
For i = 1 to (objUpload.Form("thefile").value).Count
    If (objUpload.Form("thefile").value)(i) <> "" then
        Response.write (objUpload.Form("thefile").value)(i) & "<br />"
    End if
Next
```

Because there's a third party component involved it may complicate things so I can't guarantee this will work.  Check the component's documentation if it is available, particularly with respect to counting the number of files uploaded.

Comment: Thank you so much for this and sorry for this late reply. I've tried this but I found out that it gives me an error because of the component. (btw, I wasn't even sure that this is a third party component. I'd googled it but I couldn't find their page anywhere and no documentation in our system.  Thanks for telling me that too)  I tried the uploadify as well but it also gave me IO error that I couldn't fix. I ended up to have just a single uploader for now. I have to change it to a multiple one in the future though, hopefully I will have more time to learn VBscript by then.

Comment: It's either a third party component or a custom dll.  There's no native COM component for file uploads - that's why solutions like that asp version of Uploadify use a class file.  As far as I can tell the origin of your component is a tutorial from 2001 telling you how to compile your own.  If I'm right then this is all the documentation which exists. http://www.developerfusion.com/article/1615/uploading-files-with-asp/8/

Comment: I see. Yes, the code on the link is really similar to our original file I was modifying. 
I will just get rid of this component and try uploadify for the future. It sounds easier and looks nice. Thanks so much for your help John.